# How to completely remove persistent services generated from docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There are a few services being created when executing `docker-compose up` and rightfully so because these are containers for databases etc. which should be persistent.

You may list them with this command: `docker-compose ps --services`

The removal of them is necessary because we are currently testing so we would like to have a fresh start.

How could one remove these services? (no obvious way has worked yet, new to Docker)

Comment: When you say **persistent**... Do you mean the services have associated volumes?

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu guess you are right. This is how it is called in docker language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all services containers and volumes, execute:

```
docker-compose down -v
```

If you want to remove just a single service:

```
docker-compose down -v my-database
```